# How could I refresh a line chart after the form has been minimized?

Tags: c#, refresh, minimized

In Visual C#, I built a component(not a user control) to draw a data line chart to display datas coming from socket. I put the drawing codes in the Paint event, so I called Invalidate after a new data pack comes. But when the form is minimized, it seems the drawing has been stoped. After the form is restored，there are some data in the buffer still need to be refresh , which cause a delay of the display (depends on how long the form has been keep minimized).

What is the machnism should I use to refresh the line chart even if it is not displayed?

Comment: I couldn't get the Paint event to happen when it's minimized. But I found out what I did wrong  about the delay of the line refresh. It's because the I put the data update control in the Paint event. When Paint doesn't happen, old data could not be delete and new data are waiting.

Answer (score 0):

call `Invalidate()` to tell the system that, next time it becomes visible it should be 
redrawn (you're already doing this)

then call `Update()` which forces the redraw to take place right now (you might want to make this call only if you are minimized)

Alternatively simply call the

`Refresh()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried Update() or Refresh() in a Forms.Timer event, but it still haven't refresh during minimize.